# How to form an array of dictionaries for multilevel(any number) tableview from the core data object

Tags: objective-c, arrays, linked-list, nsdictionary, multi-level

I need to create array of dictionaries, of data coming from a database object. This array of dictionaries can be of multiple level,and has a parent child relationship depending upon the level.

From the array form I need to create a multilevel table view (level can be any depending upon the data loaded)

Depending upon the catal_id of the coredata object, next set of Catal objects are loaded from the database. Code supporting is shown as below.

**I want to create the array as shown in the image**
[image]

**From the above load of loadMainCatalData I am able to load the table but on didSelectRowAtIndexPath I am not able to form the proper array for the expand collapse table. Catal object gets added twice, on viewDidLoad.**

There is some issue with function.

**Please help to form the proper array to load the table. Stuck here **.

The coredata object is of the below format:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x109c3b7a0>(
<Catal: 0x104cccfb0>
 (entity: Catal; id: 0xd000000008880006 <x-coredata://F849E220-C905-4359-8CD5-18D5E35FC13A/Catal/p546> ; data: {
    breadcrumb = "";
    "catal_id" = "SNV2";
    "id_ni" = 1;
    "id_parent" = 0;
    imgId = 1;
    title = "Adventure";
    "nb_element" = 1010;
    order = 38;
}),
<Catal: 0x104ccd3f0> (entity: Catal; id: 0xd000000006e40006 <x-coredata://F849E220-C905-4359-8CD5-18D5E35FC13A/Catal/p441> ; data: {
    breadcrumb = "";
    "catal_id" = "SNV1";
    "id_ni" = 1;
    "id_parent" = 0;
    imgId = 38;
    title = Gros;
    "nb_element" = 1366;
    order = 82;
}),
<Catal: 0x104ccd6e0> (entity: Catal; id: 0xd00000000a500006 <x-coredata://F849E220-C905-4359-8CD5-18D5E35FC13A/Catal/p660> ; data: <fault>),
<Catal: 0x104ccd790> (entity: Catal; id: 0xd000000005d40006 <x-coredata://F849E220-C905-4359-8CD5-18D5E35FC13A/Catal/p373> ; data: <fault>),
<Catal: 0x104ccd940> (entity: Catal; id: 0xd00000000acc0006 <x-coredata://F849E220-C905-4359-8CD5-18D5E35FC13A/Catal/p691> ; data: <fault>)
)
```

My code goes as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!self.catalList || self.catalList.count == 0) {
        [self loadDataCatal];
        isAlreadyInserted = NO;
    }
}

- (void)loadDataCatal{
  [self loadMainCatalData];
  self.arForTable = [NSMutableArray array];
     [self.arForTable addObjectsFromArray:self.arrayOriginal];
}

-(void)loadMainCatalData {
    NSMutableArray *arrCatalList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (catLevel == NULL){
        [arrCatalList addObjectsFromArray:[Catal fillDataCatal:@"0" :@"0"]];
    }
    self.arrayOriginal = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (Catal *objCatal in arrCatalList){
        ProductCategoryFilter *objProductCatFilter = [[ProductCategoryFilter alloc] init];
        [objProductCatFilter setCatalCategory:objCatal];
        NSMutableArray *arr = [self loadSubCatalData:objCatal];
        [objProductCatFilter setArrCatalSubCategory:arr];
        [self.arrayOriginal addObject:objProductCatFilter];
    }

}

-(NSMutableArray *)loadSubCatalData:(Catal *)objCatal{
    NSMutableArray *arrSubCatal = [NSMutableArray array];
    ProductCategoryFilter *objProductCatFilter = [[ProductCategoryFilter alloc] init];
    [objProductCatFilter setCatalCategory:objCatal];
    NSArray *arrCatal = [Catal fillDataCatal:objCatal.catal_id :@""];

        NSMutableArray *arrSubCat = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (Catal *subCatal in arrCatal){
            ProductCategoryFilter *objSubCatFilter = [[ProductCategoryFilter alloc] init];
            [objSubCatFilter setCatalCategory:subCatal];
            NSMutableArray *arr = [self loadSubCatalData:subCatal];
            [objSubCatFilter setArrCatalSubCategory:arr];
            [arrSubCat addObject:objSubCatFilter];
        }
        [objProductCatFilter setArrCatalSubCategory:arrSubCat];

    [arrSubCatal addObject:objProductCatFilter];

    return arrSubCatal;
}

// the ProductCategoryFilter class
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Catal+CoreDataClass.h"

@interface ProductCategoryFilter : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) Catal* catalCategory;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray * arrCatalSubCategory;
@end



  // Catal CoreDataObject
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import "Catal+CoreDataClass.h"

+(BOOL)fillSubDataCatal:(NSString *)catal_id
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[CoreDataHelper getInstance] managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Catal" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate;
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_parent == %@", catal_id];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    DebugLog(@"[fetchedObjects count] : %lu",(unsigned long)fetchedObjects.count);
    if([fetchedObjects count] > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier =@"AMG_PP_SubCategoryTableCell";

    AMG_PP_SubCategoryTableCell *cell  = (AMG_PP_SubCategoryTableCell *) [self.tblProductCategory dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell =(AMG_PP_SubCategoryTableCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
    ProductCategoryFilter *objCat = [self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [cell.imgRadio setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlusIcon"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = objCat.catalCategory.libelle; //] [ valueForKey:@"name"];
//    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        AMG_PP_SubCategoryTableCell *cell = (AMG_PP_SubCategoryTableCell *)[self.tblProductCategory cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.tblProductCategory deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ProductCategoryFilter *objCatal = [self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([[objCatal arrCatalSubCategory] count] > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *ar=[objCatal arrCatalSubCategory];
        if(ar != nil){
            isAlreadyInserted=NO;

            for(ProductCategoryFilter *dInner in ar ){
                NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
                isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
                if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
            }

            if(isAlreadyInserted) {
                [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
            } else {
                NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
                NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
                for(ProductCategoryFilter *dInner in ar ){
                    [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                    [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
                }
                 [cell.imgRadio setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MinusIcon"]];
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            }
        }


    }
}

-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{

    for(ProductCategoryFilter *dInner in ar ){
        NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        NSMutableArray *arInner=[dInner arrCatalSubCategory];
        if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
            if (arInner != nil) {
                [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
            }

        }

        if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
            [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.tblProductCategory deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                                         [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]
                                                         ]
                                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple code which help you in understanding the how to create a array of dictionary :

```
var arrayOfDict = [[String : String]]()
let dict1  = ["FirstName" : "Abc" , "LastName" : "XYZ"]
let dict2 = ["HouseNo" : "WW49", "Locality" : "GymKhana"]
let dict3 = ["City" : "mnb", "State" : "lkop" , "Country" : "mkl"]

arrayOfDict.append(dict1)
arrayOfDict.append(dict2)
arrayOfDict.append(dict3)

print(arrayOfDict)
```